# OpenGL ES 2 vs Drawing on Canvas (SurfaceView) - which is better?

Tags: android

Say I want to look into the process of making 2d games, with the amount of graphics, movement, etc, similar to AngryBirds.

So I wanted to ask, what kind of drawing method should I use - simple drawing sprites on canvas (SurfaceView) or should I better look into using OpenGL ES 2 ?

What do you think are the pros and cons of one over the other?

Also I'm looking for a way to make sprites move like physical objects, I guess there was some Box2D engine for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create 2D game go for the Canvas(SurfaceView) instead of OpenGL. OpenGL is mostly used for 3D Games and its is not easy to do implementation in OpenGL.